# IPN or something equivalent For Paypal Payment Advanced

Tags: php, opencart, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway

**How can i use IPN for PAYPAL PAYMENT ADVANCED?**

I am working on a website where the payment system needs to be **changed from paypal standard to paypal payment advanced**. The transaction type for the website is almost always a 'Authorization'. So, we capture payment later when we ship the item.

The problem i am facing is **finding a way to receive IPN or something equivalent** for it to update the system if transaction has been captured. I used to use the CUSTOM and notify_url for reciving IPN in the old system. But I dont know what to use for PAYPAL ADVANCED.

note: i am using  OpenCart, PHP and layout A for paypal advanced.

Comment: If it is Paypal, it shouldn't matter right? Paypal will send everything through IPN regardless of the method I believe.

Comment: It doesnot. I talked to Paypal, and they said IPN doesnt work for paypal advanced. I am trying to see if there is any other simpler passive way, because i dont want to modify my framework too much just to adjust for Paypal.

Comment: I think i fixed it though. @DavidNguyen you were kinda right. It looks like i can use the same function because i have both the systems. I just could pass CUSTOM and NOTIFYURL even through the payflow Curl.